# Taking a derivative of a magnitude of a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I have found several questions including this as a step in the explanation, but have not been able to find an explicit explanation of how to take a derivative of a magnitude of a vector.

I am trying to take the derivative d/dt ||r'(t)|| but don't know how to address the magnitude signs.

Comment: Do you have a formula for $r(t)$ and for $r'(t)$? If so get the formula for $||r'(t)||$ which will be a 1-var function of $t,$ then do derivative of that.

Comment: What is your norm? The one derived from the dot product?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net r(t) is a path -- what would the norm derived from the dot product be?

Comment: If you, like me, came here trying to do machine learning square loss like minimizing $||y-Xw||$^2 by differentiating and setting equal to 0, I don't recommend trying the solutions here. Instead, just use the dot product definition of magnitude to get to $(y-Xw)^T(y-Xw)$, do out the multiplication and then use (84) of the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). A tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnNH3SxyZEI)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will assume that you are working with the euclidian norm and the dot product. Let $v(t)$ be a vector:
$$v(t) \cdot v(t)=|v(t)|^2$$
And
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}|v(t)|^2}{\mathrm{d}t}=2|v(t)|\frac{\mathrm{d}|v(t)|}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
Which implies that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}|v(t)|}{\mathrm{d}t}&=\frac{1}{2|v(t)|}\frac{\mathrm{d}|v(t)|^2}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
&=\frac{1}{2|v(t)|}\frac{\mathrm{d}(v(t) \cdot v(t))}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
&=\frac{1}{2|v(t)|}\left(v(t) \cdot v'(t)+v'(t) \cdot v(t)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2|v(t)|}\left(2v(t) \cdot v'(t)\right)\\
&=\frac{v(t) \cdot v'(t)}{|v(t)|}
\end{align}$$

Comment: (If anyone is unfamiliar with the notation, $v^\prime(t) = \dot{v}(t) = \frac{d v(t)}{d t}$.)

Answer (score 1):

If the norm is derived from the dot product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$, then

$$\frac{d\Vert r^\prime(t) \Vert}{dt} = \frac{\langle r^\prime(t),r^{\prime \prime}(t)\rangle}{\Vert r^\prime(t)\Vert}.$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got that?

Comment: Using the [chain rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). A more simple way is to use the coordinates and the fact that for a vector $x=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ (in dimension $n$), you have $\Vert x \Vert = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \dots +x_n^2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \left| {r(t)} \right|^2  = r_{\,x} (t)^2  + r_{\,y} (t)^2  +  \cdots   \cr 
  & 2\left| {r(t)} \right|{d \over {dt}}\left| {r(t)} \right| = 2\left( {r_{\,x} (t)r_{\,x} '(t) + r_{\,y} (t)r_{\,y} '(t) +  \cdots } \right)  \cr 
  & {d \over {dt}}\left| {r(t)} \right| = {{r_{\,x} (t)r_{\,x} '(t) + r_{\,y} (t)r_{\,y} '(t) +  \cdots } \over {\left| {r(t)} \right|}} \cr} 
$$